# How to show sliding panel ONLY in the mobile version of my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

Which, do you think, is the most elegant solution to show a sliding panel with the menu only in the mobile version of my website. I am going to build it using the 1140px grid and will have a regular horizontal nav for the desktop/iPad version and when it scales down to mobile, I'd like to hive the regular nav and move it to this sliding panel.
I thought about using jQuery Mobile, but this means that I have to base my whole website on it (correct me if I'm wrong here). I was thinking about having it there all the time but hiding in with CSS and showing it only for the mobile version. This, however, means that the user will have to download everything, no matter of the device he is using.
Any help is appreciated, guys.

Comment: I am going to use CSS media queries even if I don't make a sliding panel, I am aware of them. How exactly to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Set the div to not display regularly and then afterwards, show it only for media devices with a screen width of 480px and smaller.

```
#divID {
    display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #divID {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, what your doing to need to do then is structure it before using margin, width, height, list-style, etc and then just change all those within the media query. There's not much more we can do when you provide no code examples.